# Find the minimum value of this rational expression

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

A question asks, "If x is a postive real number, then find the minimum value of 
$[{x + (1/x)}^6  - {x^6 + (1/x)^6} - 2]/ [{x + (1/x)}^3 + {x^3 + (1/x)^3}]$

[Question Image](https://ibb.co/6n6G67g)

My try:- I expanded and simplified the numerator and then applied AM - GM and got Numerator $>= 12*sqrt(10) + 18$. Then applying AM-GM on denominator, we get denominator $>= 4*sqrt(6)$.

But I do not know how to combine these two results.
How can I proceed?

Comment: Please use LaTeX.

Comment: Do you know how to use derivatives to find maxima or minima?

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{(x+\frac{1}{x})^6-(x^6+\frac{1}{x^6})-2}{(x+\frac{1}{x})^3+x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}}$$

Comment: @Leo Sorry I do not know Latex.

Comment: @Leo Yes but how can I use derivatives here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes.

Comment: @Aqua Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It simplifies to $$3(x+\frac{1}{x})$$, now use that $$a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2$$ for $a>0$